AlpineJs Condition with Multiple Values like inArray
I am using AlpineJs to build a small project. We have multiple choices that change box color once its active/inactive. The problem that I only know how to achieve it if it is single value.
Livewire (php)
class ListingPromoteForm extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public Listing $listing;
    protected $marketplaces;
    public $userCurrency;
    public $total = 0;
    public $selected = [];
    public $modalOpen = false;
    public function render()
    {
        $this->userCurrency = Auth::user()->userCurrency()->where('is_primary', true)->first();
        $this->marketplaces = Marketplace::paginate(10);
        return view('livewire.form.listing-promote-form',['marketplaces' => $this->marketplaces]);
    }

    public function submit(){
        dd($this->selected);
    }
}

Livewire (component)
<div class="p-2" x-data="{total:0,selected:@entangle('selected')}" wire:ignore>
    <x-page-box class="mb-3 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg">
        <x-heading-2>{{ __('Current :name', ['name' => __('Balance')]) }}</x-heading-2>
        <div class="flex justify-end">
            <span class="font-bold">Rp {{ number_format($userCurrency->amount) }}</span>
        </div>
    </x-page-box>
    <!-- Showing total -->
    <div class="p-2 flex justify-between">
        <span>{{ __(':name Total', ['name' => __('Cost')]) }}</span>
        <span x-text="total"></span>
    </div>
    <form wire:submit="submit">
        <ul class="divide-y-2 border mb-3 max-h-[500px] overflow-y-auto">
            @foreach ($marketplaces as $item)
                <li wire:key="{{ $item->id }}">
                    <label for="selected.{{ $item->id }}"
                        :class="{{ $item->id }} in selected ? 'bg-green-100' : 'bg-white'"
                        class="p-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-100 flex justify-between items-center">
                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            <input value="{{ $item->id }}" x-model="selected" id="selected.{{ $item->id }}"
                                name="selected.{{ $item->id }}" type="checkbox"
                                class="text-gray-900 translate-y-px focus:ring-gray-700 me-2 rounded-lg block">
                            <div>
                                <p>{{ $item->website->domain }}</p>
                                <p class="text-xs"><i class="fa-solid fa-chart-simple ps-1"></i>
                                    {{ __('Traffic :amount', ['amount' => 0]) }}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <span class="text-xs">Rp {{ number_format($item->price) }}</span>
                    </label>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
        {{ $marketplaces->links() }}
        <div class="flex justify-end mt-2">
            <x-primary-button>{{ __('Submit') }} <i
                    class="ps-2 fa-solid fa-circle-arrow-right"></i></x-primary-button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <x-shared.loading-widget wire:loading.flex>{{ __('Processing') }}</x-shared.loading-widget>
</div>

I really appreciate any answer. I have read alpineJs documentation but have no luck. Thank you

Why do you have square brackets [] around the class when selected is an array?

If selected is an array it should work, if selected is an object you can use the form 'key' in selected
The condition does not require to be included in an array, but can work also if it is included:
Object
<label for="selected.{{$item->id}}"
       class="p-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-100 flex justify-between items-center"
       :class="'{{$item->id}}' in selected ? 'bg-green-100' : 'bg-white'"
>
    The label
</label>

Array
<label for="selected.{{$item->id}}"
       class="p-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-100 flex justify-between items-center"
       :class="selected.includes({{$item->id}}) ? 'bg-green-100' : 'bg-white'"
>
    The label
</label>

Another option is to use a JSON expression, but it's a bit verbose in this situation:
:class="{'bg-green-100': selected.includes({{$item->id}}), 'bg-white': !selected.includes({{$item->id}})}"

Edit after additional informations
From the posted code I can see that the selected variable is an array that contains the values of the selected checkboxes.
So your initial code was on the right track, (in my previous response there was a typo, now fixed) the selected.includes() is the correct method to check if the checkbox is selected, anyway, since the value attributes taken from the DOM are always strings and includes() applies a strict comparson, we must add quotes to the searched value:
:class="selected.includes('{{$item->id}}') ? 'bg-green-100' : 'bg-white'"

note the quotes surrounding {{$item->id}}
The problem of the mismatch with the fifth and the first item does not seem related to the class switch, you can debug it inspecting the DOM with the browser, also you can add this Alpine inspection into the main <div> to have a live check of the ids selected :
<div x-text="selected"></div>


I've tried both above but it did not work. I am trying to make the output and it shows like this 2,3,4,5. If I did it like this (:class="{{ $item->id }} in selected ? 'bg-green-100' : 'bg-white'"). It works but there is bug, If click the fifth item, the first item is applied.

I've hypothesized a few scenarios but if you want a more precise answer you need to provide more specific information. Where does selected come from? How is it defined and structured? Please edit your question and include any additional information that may be helpful.

I have edited it with full code

I've added some informations to my answer

It works, dunno we need to add quotes there. Thank you

Do you know about using includeNot? I searching through alpineJS docs but cannot find it. Or should i just use like this? !items.includes()

!items.includes() is the right expression, note that it's a generic JS code, it's not specific forAlpineJS

Okay, I just got that inside x-text, x-data, etc we can also set javascript there.
